# Can I render only the last x lines of code?

Tags: rendering

I'm working on a document in `TeXmaker` and it is getting quite long. The problem is that it takes upwards of 15 seconds to render each time because it renders the full document. Is there a way I can make it only render say the last 100 lines of code?

Comment: You are probably looking for `\includeonly` or similar.

Comment: Maybe mactex and flash mode, if that still exists.

Comment: if your chapters are in separate files you can use `\includeonly` just to process the one you are working on. On the other hand,if you write for say a couple of hours then spend 15 seconds updating the pdf view, it's not such a big deal, do you never pause for 15 seconds where you could have the machine run tex?

Comment: Other options that i currently use are( 1) creating custom format with `mylatexformat` package and/or (2) use the `version` package to define an evironmemtthat latex will not process.